Angular v12: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: d3 is not defined ReferenceError: d3 is not defined
Angular v12, try to use d3, nvd3 (not ng2-nvd3). Compile ok, but run time error.

default-node_modules_d3_src_index_js.js:2 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in
promise): ReferenceError: d3 is not defined ReferenceError: d3 is not
defined
at nv.d3.js:18:7
at 75301 (nv.d3.js:15671:2)
at webpack_require (bootstrap:19:1)
at 89275 (src_app_mypage_module_ts.js:15:62)
at webpack_require (bootstrap:19:1)
at 13111 (pageone.component.html:2:39)
at webpack_require (bootstrap:19:1)
at Function.webpack_require (bootstrap:19:1)
at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:368:26)
at resolvePromise (zone.js:1193:31)
at resolvePromise (zone.js:1147:17)
at zone.js:1260:17
at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:402:31)
at core.mjs:25948:55
at AsyncStackTaggingZoneSpec.onInvokeTask (core.mjs:25948:36)
at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:401:60)
at Object.onInvokeTask (core.mjs:26249:33)
at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:401:60)
at Zone.runTask (zone.js:173:47)

Here is what's done:
npm install d3
npm install nvd3
npm install @types/d3 --save-dev
npm install @types/nvd3 --save-dev

Component .HTML:
<div id='chart' class='span4'>
    <svg style='height:500px;width:100%'> </svg>
</div>

.TS:
import * as d3 from 'd3';  
import * as nv from 'nvd3';  

ngOnInit(): void 
{
    this.myservice.subscribe(resp=> {
        this.chartdata = resp.data;
        this.drawchart();
    });
}
  
drawchart()
{
    nv.addGraph(()=> {
    var chart = nv.models.pieChart()
      .x((d) => { return d.label })
      .y((d) => { return d.value })
      .showLabels(true)
      .donut(true)         
      .labelThreshold(0.001) 
      .labelType("key").donutRatio(0.60); 

    d3.select("#chart svg")
        .datum(this.chartdata)
        .call(chart as any);
    ...
    });
}

Update: Thanks to @Naren Murali's solution, I'm not only able to integrate, but it works in a project has mixed d3 versions.
Note: nvd3 v1.8.6 is perfect

Make sure you installed d3 with the below command
npm i d3@^3.5.17

Because this is the version that nvd3 seems to support well
If this does not work. Include the script imports as shown below!
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/novus/nvd3/v1.8.1/build/nv.d3.min.js"></script>
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/novus/nvd3/v1.8.1/build/nv.d3.css"
/>

Then we can use the below code, to create a basic chart
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    <div id='chart' class='span4'>
        <svg style='height:500px;width:100%'> </svg>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  chartdata!: { label: string; value: number }[];

  height = 350;
  width = 350;
  chart2: any;

  testdata = [
    { key: 'One', y: 5 },
    { key: 'Two', y: 2 },
    { key: 'Three', y: 9 },
    { key: 'Four', y: 7 },
    { key: 'Five', y: 4 },
    { key: 'Six', y: 3 },
    { key: 'Seven', y: 0.5 },
  ];

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.chartdata = [
      { label: 'test', value: 20 },
      { label: 'test2', value: 20 },
      { label: 'test3', value: 20 },
      { label: 'test4', value: 20 },
    ];
    this.drawchart();
  }

  drawchart() {
    const nv = (window as any)['nv'];
    nv.addGraph(() => {
      const chart2 = nv.models
        .pieChart()
        .x(function (d: any) {
          return d.key;
        })
        .y(function (d: any) {
          return d.y;
        })
        //.labelThreshold(.08)
        //.showLabels(false)
        .width(this.width)
        .height(this.height)
        .donut(true)
        .id('donut2')
        .titleOffset(-30)
        .title('woot');

      // MAKES IT HALF CIRCLE
      chart2.pie
        .startAngle(function (d: any) {
          return d.startAngle / 2 - Math.PI / 2;
        })
        .endAngle(function (d: any) {
          return d.endAngle / 2 - Math.PI / 2;
        });
      const d3 = (window as any)['d3'];
      d3.select('#chart svg')
        //.datum(historicalBarChart)
        .datum(this.testdata)
        .transition()
        .duration(1200)
        .call(chart2);

      return chart2;
    });
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo

Works like a charm. nvd3 1.8.6 is highly recommended. Thank you!
